# Within Google Tag Manager, is there a JavaScript function for getting a user's Client ID?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, sitecore, google-tag-manager, clientid

I am attempting to write a function that will be used in a custom Javascript Variable in Google Tag Manager (GTM). What I have currently is the below:

```
function getClientID()
{        // Modify customDimensionIndex to match the index number you want to send the data to\n  
        var customDimensionIndex = 7;
        return function(model) 
    {
         model.set('dimension' + customDimensionIndex, model.get('clientId'));}
    }
```

It should get the client ID, and set the index of a Google Analytics custom dimension (as 7 in this case) to it. 
This is not returning a client ID on the page however. In GTM preview mode, there is a SessionID and SitecoreUserID, as follows:

```
user:
{ sitecoreID: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  ...
},
session:
{ id: 'aa2aaaaqaaaaaaaaaaa25eee'}
```

I suppose I could user the sitecoreID as the client ID and send that to Google Analytics. But I was wondering if there would usually be another Client ID on a page, and if so, how to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will send the client id as a custom dimension, provided you use it as a custom task on your Universal Analytics tags. Outside a task you will not be able to access the model.

Comment: Thanks. So is the model something unique to UA tags? It should then be possible to use, right

Answer (score 0):

You can get clientId by creating a Custom JavaScript variabile with this code:

```
function() {
  try {
    var trackers = ga.getAll();
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === {{GA Tracking Code}}) {
        return trackers[i].get('clientId');
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {}  
  return 'false';
}
```

Replace GA Tracking Code variabile with your Google Analytics Property.

You need to use a Window Loaded Trigger:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When testing in GTM's Preview Mode, I am getting 'false' though, even though I know I have the correct trackingID, and looking into the console, I can see the ClientID is there. Where could the error be happening?

Comment: You need a Window Loaded Trigger, I edited my answer.